# how to show the device keyboard using C++ MFC for Windows CE device?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, mfc

How to show the device keyboard using C++ MFC for Windows CE/Windows Mobile device to type in?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you probably want is [SipShowIM()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932298.aspx).